# Yielding HTML inside of a slot doesn't work for components

Tags: laravel

So I have this simple admin toolbar:

```html
    <div class="admin-toolbar {{ $class ?? '' }}">
        <i class="fas fa-user-shield"></i>
        {{ $buttons }}
    </div>
```

And I use it as such:

```html
    @admintoolbar
        @slot('buttons')
            <a href="/snippet/destroy/{{ $snippet->id }}">
                <i class="margin-left(8px) far fa-trash-alt"></i>
            </a>
        @endslot
    @endadmintoolbar
```

Surprisingly, I get `Undefined variable: buttons` at line `{{ $buttons }}`

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Also, am I correct in assuming that you've created an alias for `admintoolbar`?

Comment: @Rwd Yes, I've created the alias. Also, I'm using Laravel Framework 5.8.17